# How to assign value to a intersection type in typescript

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, intersection-types

I'm trying to write a vscode extension in typescript, I have a `ChildProcess` and I want to terminate/kill it.

```js
export declare function terminate(process: ChildProcess & {
    pid: number;
}, cwd?: string): boolean;
...
let vlsProcess: ChildProcess
```

and then I tried to call

```js
terminate(vlsProcess);
```

but I have this error:

> Argument of type 'ChildProcess' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChildProcess & { pid: number; }'.
> Type 'ChildProcess' is not assignable to type '{ pid: number; }'.
> Property 'pid' is optional in type 'ChildProcess' but required in type '{ pid: number; }'

the function `terminate` is expecting an "intersection type" of

```
ChildProcess & {
    pid: number;
}
```

but I currently only have a `ChildProcess`, how can I convert a `ChildProcess` into `ChildProcess & { pid: number;}`?

I checked the ChildProcess, it has

```js
readonly pid?: number | undefined;
```

so to me, it seems to be able to convert to a `ChildProcess & { pid: number;}` but the typescript compiler says:

> Property 'pid' is optional in type 'ChildProcess' but required in type '{ pid: number; }'

How can I do this convertion?

Comment: Why do you actually have `& { pid: number; }` which makes the `pid` member mandatory, if you only have objects where this member is optional? Makes not much sense to me. What's the purpose of that addition? While you can force vlsProcess to be acceptable using a type assertion I would rather remove that addtional part instead.

Comment: @MikeLischke it's not defined by me but by vscode extension interfaces.

Comment: The only way this could work is if you check `pid`'s existence in `vlsProcess` before calling `terminate()`, to eliminate the possibility that `vlsProcess.pid` is undefined.  Unfortunately a simple `if (typeof vlsProcess.pid === "number") terminate(vlsProcess)` won't work due to a missing feature at [ms/TS#42384](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384). You can implement your own type guard function and use that instead, as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/Nl83xN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz please do. I never knew that I could make a local type guard by checking the value ahead of time and then the typescript type checking error will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way for `terminate(vlsProcess)` to compile without error is to convince the compiler that `vlsProcess` is of type `ChildProcess & { pid: number; }`, meaning it has to be a `ChildProcess` where the `pid` property is known to exist and be of type `number`.  But `vlsProcess` is declared a `ChildProcess` whose `pid` property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties).  So you need to do something with that `pid` property.

One approach would be to write a check that `typeof vlsProcess.pid === "number"` before you call `terminate(vlsProcess)`, in the hopes that such a check would [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of `vlsProcess`.  Unfortunately that doesn't work:

```
if (typeof vlsProcess.pid === "number") {
  terminate(vlsProcess); // same error 
}
```

This is essentially a missing feature of TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384)  While the check `typeof vlsProcess.pid === "number"` can narrow the apparent type of `vlsProcess.pid` from `number | undefined` to `number`, it has no effect on the apparent type of `vlsProcess` itself.  In general it would be too expensive to have a check of some subproperty like `a.b.c.d.e.f` have effects on all the parent objects, since the compiler would need to spend time synthesizing all the relevant types, most of which would be completely useless for most calls.

---

Until and unless something better happens there, we can luckily emulate this sort of narrowing by implementing a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  Like this:

```
function hasDefinedProp<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey>(
  obj: T, k: K
): obj is T & { [P in K]: {} | null } {
  return (typeof (obj as any)[k] !== "undefined");
}
```

If `hasDefinedProp(obj, k)` returns `true`, then `obj` will be narrowed from its original type to a subtype which is known to have a defined property at the `k` key.  This is written as an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `T` and `{ [P in K]: {} | null }`, the latter being equivalent to `Record<K, {} | null>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).  The type `{ [P in K]: {} | null }` is known to have a property of type `{} | null` at every key of type `K`, and `{} | null` essentially allows every value except for `undefined`. Intersecting a type with `{} | null` will serve to eliminate `undefined` from its domain, [as introduced in TypeScript 4.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing).

Note that the implementation uses the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `obj as any` to allow us to index into `obj[key]` without complaint.

---

Okay, now let's try it:

```
if (hasDefinedProp(vlsProcess, "pid")) {
  vlsProcess // ChildProcess & { pid: {} | null }
  terminate(vlsProcess); // okay
}
```

That works.  TypeScript sees the narrowed type `ChildProcess & { pid: {} | null }` to be assignable to `ChildProcess & { pid: number }`, because the `pid` property of the former is `(number | undefined) & ({} | null)` which is `number`.

And if, for some reason, `hasDefinedProp()` returns `false`, then you don't want to call `terminate(vlsProcess)` because `vlsProcess` has no `pid`.  What you *should* do in such a situation depends on your use case.  In the above it just skips the `terminate()` call, but you might want to throw an exception or something.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDgMwK4B2yMAlhAXDMFALYkHpUAUYUEywAzpwFxwDCACxKoEABTYducAGRwA3gFgAUHDhgSCPgTw0ARtQDcKgL4AaOMgDuCAPx9OMKPQDmASj56IEVMHQFjZRV6KigcdA4BYVEJdi5OBRU1LHQEclQAT3VNezgdfWo4AB84QiQcemAEQLUIGEFqABVhAhdeOEdnVsCTFRUkNExsX3gAN1ROWKl2oRFxSXi+5XwiUnI4QXROABFgCoIq2LAAHka4UCoCBASIPQArFBgLAGlzkEvruCPqGAzn4AyAD4mEk4Lc7nxGhYANZ8Z4qDxg+5wEgJM5yeRwADaYhRFGeAF0+PITMU8nhUKg4KSlKo4FgYHgoBQmL8wMAIDg4ExwXAtnyCBk3FjoQS4ABCAC8krgACIyntKghZW4eksSFzWRl2Zy4ONJgtuAA6DQIODSmWy-IGKAqxJ00J0BjMfVTeKquAAek9HXQNGw1DYUDggF4NwBEe6Z1ZrNjtFQd5hAwExXYbOBZZaaVW57WoU3FpN6onM3dIMdktApSSUdJS4IZeg7qE7GMBkxMS5wPYWIND0BlTEA)

Comment: Never imagined typescript's type is so compilated!